# Can Angular drag & drop work with mat-table with paging and sorting enabled?

Tags: angular, sorting, paging, drag, drop

I have already implemented a solution where drag and drop is possible between two mat-tables with arrays for datasources.

At the time I am using the code from [Angular Material Schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#drag-and-drop-schematic) for the drop function like the following:

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<MyObject[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  } else {
    transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

However when paging and sorting was added and I switched my datasource to `MatTableDatasource` the drag and drop functionality stopped working.

**In general, is it possible for drag & drop to work on a mat-table with paging and sorting enabled?**

Answer (score 0):

**It turns out it is actually possible for drag & drop to work on a mat-table with paging and sorting enabled.**

In short, the event type changes to **CdkDragDrop<MatTableDataSource, any>** and you have to add a **.data** more to get your data from `event.container.data` and `event.previousContainer.data` since these are wrapped up inside `MatTableDataSource`.

I had to change the drop function like this:

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<MatTableDataSource<MyObject>, any>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data.data, event.container.data.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```

If anyone has any more insight, please do share!